# Could not find class or interface (12886)

Tags: openedge

I am trying to instantiate a class from another project but I am facing the error 12886 "Could not find class or interface.

I checked the project property of OrderImporter to reference Tools project but it does not change anything.

Also, I checked in the class browser and everything seem ok. There is even an example how to use my own class but it does not works outside of the project Tools.

Does someone have an idea where I fail?
Thank you!
Sebastien

**Project OrderImporter | C:\workspace\Progress\OrderImporter\Test.cls**

```
USING Progress.Lang.*.
USING Tools.StringHelper. <-- Could not find class or interface (12886)

CLASS Test: 
    METHOD PUBLIC VOID BipBip():    
        DEFINE VARIABLE arrSplit AS System.Collections.ArrayList NO-UNDO.         
        arrSplit = Tools.StringHelper:Split("VALUE1*VALUE2*VALUE3", "*").
    END METHOD.       
END CLASS.
```

**Project Tools | C:\workspace\Progress\Tools\StringHelper.cls**

```
USING Progress.Lang.*.

CLASS Tools.StringHelper: 
    METHOD STATIC PUBLIC System.Collections.ArrayList Split(
         INPUT strValues AS CHARACTER
        ,INPUT strSeparator AS CHARACTER):

        /* doing something */
        /* returning something */
        RETURN arrReturn.

    END METHOD.
END CLASS.
```

Comment: Here a printscreen of my workspace: http://www.hollox.net/_/share/img00108.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the PROPATH for the project that needs the other project's class to include an external workspace.

Comment: Thank you Tim, as soon that I add external folder in the propath everything works!